# Нужно достать содержимое тега <strong>

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Нужно достать содержимое тега 'strong', а именно "599$" из:

```
<a href="link" class="products_content">
    <span class="products_name">product</span>
    <strong>599$</strong>
</a>
```

Пробовал:

```
productsPrice = soup.findAll('a', class_='products_content').find_all('strong')
```

Отвечает:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Я могу получить все теги с помощью find_all('strong'), но мне нужны теги strong именно внутри < a href>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, переменная `productsPrice` содержит список после `soup.findAll('a', class_='products_content')`. Вам нужно будет обратиться `find_all` к его содержимому (даже если вы знаете, что это список только с одним элементом), а не ко всему.

Пример:

```
productsPrice = soup.findAll('a', class_='products_content')[0].find_all('strong')
```

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @magat Не за что) если ответ вас устроил, пожалуйста, оцените его)

Comment: Да конечно, я тут просто еще новичок.